# Q/kdb+ read log files by chunk

Tags: kdb, ticker, chunks, q-lang

I have a task that requires me to load log files that is too big for my memory to let it load at once. Therefore I need  way to load the file by different chunks..

I know that:

```
-11!(n; filename)
```

loads first n chunk from a file, but how do I load the rest of the chunks??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log file probably calls the function upd if it is a typical tickerplant setup. Override that function to ignore the initial values on the second run, without inserting them into the table allowing you to split the loading into parts.

```
upd:{i+:1; if[i within 100000 200000; ignore x; storeSomewhere x]};
```

Then play the whole file `-11!`. Control what portions are actually stored by changing the condional in the if clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a couple more thing, for overriding the upd, which function should I use? And after I override the upd, should i just use -11!(n; filename) to get the next n lines?